# why this does not work: `\use_i_i:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}`

Tags: xetex, expl3, latex3

Why the following code does not work ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn  \cs_new_protected:Npn
\mycommand #1#2#3{ \use_i_i:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\mycommand{ abc } {  {def}  } { ghi }$
\end{document}
```

**THE ERROR**:

```
 Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje31.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(ideje31.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\l3kernel\l3deprecation.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW2\tex/latex\l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def))
(ideje31.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\mycommand #1#2#3->\use_i_i:nnn 
                                {#1}{#2}{#3}
l.8 $\mycommand{ abc } {  {def}  } { ghi }
                                          $
? 


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: As the error message says, `\use_i_i:nnn` isn't defined. Did you mean `\use_i_ii:nnn`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Right. I've just modified `\use_i_ii:nnn` to `\use_i_i:nnn` to see the result.

Comment: Well, `\use_i_i:nnn` isn't defined by `expl3`, so that's the error.  You can define it with `\cs_gset:Npn \use_i_i:nnn #1 #2 #3 {#1 #1}` (I used `\cs_gset:Npn` rather than `\cs_new:Npn` because it's a “obvious” name).  Though I don't see too much use for that...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Could you please give me the entire code ? Your suggestion gives me this error: Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\mikt xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje32.tex"
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mycommand 
                           
l.10 $\mycommand
                { abc } {  {def}  } { ghi }$
? 


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________

Comment: This is the code: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn  \cs_gset:Npn
\mynewcommand #1#2#3{ \use_i_i:nnn #1 #2 #3 {#1 #1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\mycommand{ abc } {  {def}  } { ghi }$

\end{document} `

Comment: No, it's the same MWE as yours _plus_ the definition in my previous comment.  But what exactly are your trying to achieve?  As I said, the command `\use_i_i:nnn` seems weird (possible, but weird). If you tell what you are trying to accomplish I may be able to offer proper help.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm trying to construct a MWE of your `\use_i_i:nnn` I have this, but it gives an error: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn  \cs_gset:Npn %\cs_new_protected:Npn
\mycommand #1#2#3{ \use_i_i:nnn #1 #2 #3 {#1 #1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\mycommand{ abc } {  {def}  } { ghi }$
\end{document} ` Could you create a MWE of `_i_i` for me in my OQ ? However with `\use_i_ii:nnn` it does compile but I need `\use_i_i:nnn`.

Comment: I meant that the command `\use_i_i:nnn` doesn't exist, so you have to define it.  Here, try this: https://pastebin.com/raw/0YVtnuS3

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Your pastebin is of great value to me, it works as expected. Anyway, what does `:Npn` say / mean ? I reading [this](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) but it's far too complicated.

Comment: In `expl3` what follows the colon is the argument specification by convention. So it tells you that this command takes three arguments, an `N`-type (which is a single token, e.g., a macro name), a `p`-type (macro parameter text), and an `n`-type (normal argument).